# query a sql database table with a drop-down and display the result

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, drop-down-menu

This may look obvious and should be covered somewhere else but after several weeks i have read thro hundreds of examples, more than 6 books and hundreds of searches and checks there appears to be no answer.

What is the code required to query a mysql table and then display the result?

My connection and drop-down box work fine- the code is below. (I am working with wordpress and "insert php" plugin.

So to be clear about my question; what is the code required to query a table with a drop-down box selection and then display the result on the same page. the result will be a row from the table.

```
$sql = "SELECT activity FROM mytable";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='activity'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['activity'] . "'>" . $row['activity']    .      "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: what is not working with your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve is when an option is selected from the drop down you want to query the DB based on that value? You need to post that value and pass it to a query and your query will be something like

```
 "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE activity='selected_option_value'"
```

Comment: I'd like to thank people who took the time to respond. Sadly the problem continues. The problem is the craft like nature of these software platforms, art not logic. Is there a logic based and functional software platform for web development or has that possibility passed?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('#SelectID').change(function(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../example.php",
  data: "{selectedvalue: " + $(this).val() + "}",
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
  success: function(result){
      $('#div').html(result);  
   }
  });
});
```

And then in example.php file write the respective query with the received value.return the value of the query